# How to get the facebook photo from fbid using FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

It is weird sick in this situation. I know the answer but it does not work.

I use php to write a photo upload system. The picture will upload to facebook from my server and it return me the `fbid`. So I can use this `fbid` to run a FQL to get the photo's different size. The FQL is:

```
SELECT src_small, src_big, images FROM photo WHERE object_id=[fbid]
```

This work good in my php system. It return an array that contain different picture size of url. I save them in database including the `fbid`. Sometime it get `NoPic` words, so I decide to check this photo array from facebook. I run the FQL in my system again and also try the facebook graph API tools. Both of them return empty array set.

Then I use the facebook link to check if the object exist, it work.

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=220817144722724

This means the object exist, but I cannot get it from FQL anymore...
How can I get it again?

Comment: It works with me. Using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), could you: **1**. Run `SELECT aid,owner,name FROM album WHERE owner=me()`. **2**. Select the album ID where you've uploaded your photo to. **3**. Run `SELECT pid, src_big, aid, object_id FROM photo WHERE aid="THE_ALBUM_ID_YOU_JUST_GOT"`. **4**. Check whether the photo you just uploaded is really present? Please, update your initial post with more information. Also, what is the Graph API query you used to post your photo? Did you post the photo in a new album or exiting album?

Comment: mmm...This is even more weird... I use facebook developer graph API tool to run the first FQL. It return empty array.... About the upload method, I use facebook php API: $photo = $this->facebook->api('/'.$user_fbid.'/photos', 'POST', $content), which the $content had the photo link.

Answer (score 0):

If you successfully uploaded your photo, it means that you undoubtedly set the `photo_upload` permission. Unfortunately, this permission only allows you to `POST` photos, but not to `GET` them.

Therefore, I suppose you forgot to set the `user_photos` permission. Or perhaps didn't you set it at the right place or wasn't it re-used by your FQL query?

That must be it, because I tried it and everything is OK on Facebook's side.